# Testing VSCode Extension: Path file:///... does not point to a valid extension test runner

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to follow [official documentation and samples](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension) for testing VSCode Extensions and setting up Mocha as test runner.

I see that test instance appears on the screen but then in fails with the following error:

```
Error: Path file:///Users/myusername/extension-folder/out/tests/suites/index.js does not point to a valid extension test runner.
```

And my `index.ts` (compiled to ./out/tests/suites/index.js) looks like

```
import * as path from 'path';
import Mocha from 'mocha';
import glob from 'glob';


export function run(): Promise<void> {
  // Create the mocha test
  const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    color: true
  });

  const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

  return new Promise((c, e) => {
    glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot }, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return e(err);
      }

      // Add files to the test suite
      files.forEach(f => mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, f)));

      try {
        // Run the mocha test
        mocha.run(failures => {
          if (failures > 0) {
            e(new Error(`${failures} tests failed.`));
          } else {
            c();
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        e(err);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or have failures in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. In my case the culprit was that the `out/tests/suites/index.js` contained a default export, but `test-electron` expected a named export `run()`.

That's not the problem that you're having though. Here's [a link to the line in VSCode source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/dd4c9da8593873263d96bb2f7d36f4e722cd2808/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostExtensionService.ts#L730) which produces this error. One possibility is that the file path is incorrect. Just double-check it by e.g. running in terminal:

```
ls /Users/myusername/extension-folder/out/tests/suites/index.js
```